# C# How to deserialize this kind of JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file like below, the first field has more than 500 values, how can I deserialize to C# class at bottom?

```json
[
  {
    "E1001": { "MESSAGE": "", "CODE": 1001 }
  },
  {
    "E1002": { "MESSAGE": "", "CODE": 1002 }
  }
]
```

```
public class RootModel 
{
  public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
  public ErrorDetail Details { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorDetailModel 
{
  public string Message { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Mostly a guess, but would a `Dictionary<string, ErrorDetailModel>` work?

Comment: Not able to get Dictionary to work. This one is close: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z3KJj5 , but still require to know all the values first.

Comment: You question is absolutely unclear.  What is the first and the second field? What is the difference between first and the second field.  Can you show the bigger json, that we could see what do you mean?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but... the JSON doc you shared demonstrates an *anti-pattern* - you've stored actual values as your keys. This is going to cause a lot of issues, and you should consider rebuilding your JSON properly (e.g. something like `{ "ErrorString" : "E1001",  "Message": "", "Code": 1001 }`

Comment: Also: You shouldn't be linking to additional details, in comments. All details should be in your question.

Comment: Deserialize to `List<Dictionary<string, ErrorDetailModel>>`.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I end up using AdditionalProperties, it will map all "un-mapped" values to JsonSchema object, JsonScheme give me List<key,value>, key is the error code, and value is `{ "MESSAGE": "", "CODE": 1001 }`.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchema_AdditionalProperties.htm

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like this

```
List<RootModel> rootModels = JArray.Parse(json).Select(jo =>((JObject)jo).Properties().First())
                                               .Select(prop =>   new RootModel {
                                                ErrorCode = prop .Name,
                                                Details=prop.Value.ToObject<ErrorDetail>()
                                                }).ToList();
```